# Custom localisation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, localization

There are options to select an language from the list of Language in my application i.e. English, Gujarati, Hindi.

After the selection, all the texts inside app should change and display according to language selection.

**Note that** This is not normal localisation (means selecting language from settings and then it reflects in app)

The question is How can I change the text content according to selected value of Language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this article: https://medium.com/@podcoder/flutter-localization-a39402757a42 (https://github.com/podcoder/flutter_localization)

This is an easy way to localize an application without using the system language.
Hope this helps.

I am currently using this method and it works very well.